# Deleted Files or 0kb siill showing up in directory in Win10. How to get rid of them?

Tags: windows-10

As you can see by the pictures these files are 0kb except the third file and all when trying to delete say cannot find file...

[image: 0kn files on]

[image: trying to delete]

This is a problem for me because I run a Karoake co. My hosting software crashes when I load up one of these 0Kb files and try to load the song. I know they are zip files but the hosting software reads the mp3 and cdg files within the zip to play the music and onscreen lyrics to be sung. The host software crashes and I have to load it again which inconveniences my clients and singers. If I download/rip the track again and add it to the host data base both files show up and I do not know which is the working one. I know I could just name the working one file_working.zip but that would still create doubles on my system and my songbook creation software uses the file names to create the books and it would look unprofessional to have  bunch of songs listed in the book as:

BWAY- Hedwig And The Angry Inch
Angry Inch
Angry Inch_working
Wig In A Box
Wig In A Box_working, etc?

I have tried unlocker and Iobit Unlocker to get rid of them but they also claim that the files don't exist (even the one that shows Mb)

Any ideas on how to remove these empty files?

Comment: Did you try simply refreshing the Explorer window, and/or rebooting the system yet, to see if they go away?  Have you done a disk check on the drive to see if it's having problems (ie: `chkdsk D:`)?

Comment: Yes to all they are still there or they still show up in my hosting software

Comment: Are these files in a single directory, or a tree, with sub-directories?

Answer (score 0):

I think these steps might help you.

1. Simply "**Refresh**" the directory, or even better, restart the computer.
2. Have you tried to [delete the file from a **command prompt**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55728-file-delete-command-prompt.html) (maybe [**safe mode**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode) might help with this.)
3. Open properties, see if it is **blocked** (happens sometimes with files downloaded from the internet) if it is, [unblock it](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5357-unblock-file-windows-10-a.html) and try to delete it again.
4. Finally, you could give [**LockHunter**](http://lockhunter.com/) a try and see if LockHunter is able to delete the file.

If any of these fixed your problem please let us know which one fixed the problem.